# document.GetElementByid in very easy script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have this code but I don't know why the "GetElementByID" function doesn't work, anybody can help me?

The function:

```
function Disabilita(control)
    {
        if (control.checked)
        {
            alert ("checkbox ceccata");
            document.getElementById(rag_soc_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById(nome_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById(cognome_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById(nazione_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById(provincia_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById(comune_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
        }
        else
        alert ("checkbox non ceccata");
        {
            document.getElementById(rag_soc_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById(nome_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById(cognome_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById(nazione_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById(provincia_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById(comune_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

The element who the function has assigned

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="dati-sped-fatt" id="dati-sped-fatt" onClick="Disabilita(this)">
```

both alerts appear but none of controls get disabled.

Comment: Looks like you are missing quotes around your ids, maybe it should be like `document.getElementById("rag_soc_spedizione").disabled ...`

Comment: Try `true` instead of `TRUE`. There are better ways of writing this, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the id name in the colons. try this:

```
document.getElementById("rag_soc_spedizione").disabled="disabled";
```

Comment: shit, i m stupid i forgot the quotes! ...thanks for help and sorry for the waste of time

Comment: @Jacopo no issue. it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the only problem but all getelementbyid's should have quotes around the id

```
document.getElementById(rag_soc_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("rag_soc_spedizione").disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

3 problems! first TRUE and False is not valid, you must use true or false, and

```
document.getElementById(comune_spedizione).disabled=TRUE;
    }
    else
    alert ("checkbox non ceccata");
    {
        document.getElementById(rag_soc_spedizione).disabled=FALSE;
```

alert cause error!, your if statement raise an error and javascript will not work

first get rid of the if else error then use document.getElementById("rag_soc_spedizione").disabled="disabled";

3rd problem > the parameter for getElementById is string

Answer (score 0):

check you have not put curly braces for else,

so its executing alert and then setting all elements to false,
by dedault if you dont put braces i will execute only single line of code

```
function Disabilita(control)
    {
        if (control.checked)
        {
            alert ("checkbox ceccata");
            document.getElementById('rag_soc_spedizione').disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById('nome_spedizione').disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById('cognome_spedizione').disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById('nazione_spedizione').disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById('provincia_spedizione').disabled=TRUE;
            document.getElementById('comune_spedizione').disabled=TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
          alert ("checkbox non ceccata");

            document.getElementById('rag_soc_spedizione').disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById('nome_spedizione').disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById('cognome_spedizione').disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById('nazione_spedizione').disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById('provincia_spedizione').disabled=FALSE;
            document.getElementById('comune_spedizione').disabled=FALSE;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this work

```
document.getElementById("rag_soc_spedizione").disabled=true;
```

for re-enable the input use this

```
document.getElementById("rag_soc_spedizione").disabled=false;
```

whit "true" and "false" NOT "TRUE" or "FALSE"

thanks all for advices